# Passing data to container view

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using Storyboard to build up my app:
[image]

And I know that I can pass data from "First View Controller" to next controller by using something like:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"some_segue"]) {
        vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.data = @"data_i_want_to_pass";
    }
}
```

But now, the data is passing to the "Tab Bar Controller", not "Discover Table View Controller". Is there any way that I can pass data from "First View Controller" to "Discover View Controller"? Thanks.

Comment: Will the data you want to pass be available when the app starts up? I ask this because all of those controllers you show will be instantiated at startup.

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the reference of "First View Controller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's ok to pass the data at app startup (because that's when all these controllers will be instantiated, and the embed segue will be called), then you can pass the data to the tab bar controller, and that controller will have to pass it on to the one you want. So you'll have to subclass the tab bar controller, and pass the data like you show in your question. Then in the tab bar controller, you could put something like this in viewDidLoad:

```
DiscoverViewController *dvc = [(UINavigationController *)self.viewControllers[0] topViewController];
dvc.propIWantToSet =  self.propThatGotSet;
```

It doesn't seem likely though, that the data that you want to pass will be available immediately at startup -- if it were, then you could just hard code it into DiscoverViewController in the first place. In that case, in FirstViewController, you can get access to the tab bar controller with self.childViewControllers[0]. Once you have that reference, you can get the reference to DiscoverViewController like I showed above.

Comment: I got it, thanks. Actually, I am trying to control "First View Controller" from "Discover View Controller" (eg. change the background color), so I need to pass the reference of "First View Controller" to "Discover View Controller", and after that I can assign delegate to "Discover View Controller". I've solved it by your solution, thanks again, but is there any better way to do it?

Comment: `FirstViewController *fvc = (FirstViewController*) self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController;` `[fvc doSomething];` This is another solution I've tried. It works but ugly...

Answer (score 1):

```
use it :

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PushToProdct"]) {
        DiscoverViewController *discoverViewController   =   segue.destinationViewController;

        discoverViewController.data=@"Data you want to pass";
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because there is no segue to DiscoverViewController. The connection to it is a relationship, not a segue, and it doesn't have an identifier.

Comment: segue.destinationViewController is the TabBarController as I mentioned in my question.